# MFC: Is there any sample or instructions on how to use the Large Icons feature of CMFCToolBar?

Tags: mfc, toolbar

I've searched but nowhere have I found the proper way to use the `CMFCToolBar` "Large Icon" feature.  What is that feature and how is it used?

TIA!!

Comment: The Large Images feature can be turned on by the user by clicking the little "Customize" button at the bottom-right corner of your toolbar. You can also set it programmatically. You can specify (additional) large images. The MFC "normal" size is 16x15, which is very inconvenient if you want to add clipart images (they are usually 16x16 and you have to edit them, which is not always easy). If you don't add large images, the framework will display the normal ones doubled in size, which looks not very nice. First try to turn Large Images On - it will be ugly, but check if you can enable it.

Comment: I see the customize button and can chose which toolbar items to show, reset toolbar, but don't see a large icon option?

Comment: You have to click the button, select Add or Remove Buttons->Customize->Options tab, then check the "Large Icons" check-box.

Comment: I see, for some reason my "Customize" option is greyed out?

Comment: okay, i created a blank project and copied over the functions that were missing.  Now I see and it looks like you use LoadToolBarEx and pass the parameters using the "hot" items as the graphics (such as m_uiLargeHotResID) (and for the tool bar menu the `m_uiMenuResID` item)

Comment: But how to set it programmatically? I can't see the codes of the callback of the "costomize" dialog

Answer (score 0):

See members m_uiLargeColdResID, m_uiLargeHotResID and m_uiLargeDisabledResID of class CMFCToolBarInfo.